# Restore system-image with "dd" while running bootable flash drive?

Tags: linux

Just wanted to know if it is possible, to restore a (system) image of the OS, while running my Fedora, which is installed on a bootable flash drive.

Thank you!

Regards, 
Chris

Comment: The answer is yes, assuming you _have_ such an image somewhere. Now, what is it that you _really_ want to know?

Comment: Hi Michael!

What I really want to know is, if the system crashs, while overwriting itself. :-)

Comment: It's not so easy to explain. I want to boot my linux with the boot stick. Then in the OS itself, I want to restore an Image of it to itself... but it could work, because afaik it runs completely in the ram. because of that, it should be possible to overwrite the flash drive and after reboot, there shoul be my clean installation of the image.... i hope so, but I'm not sure, that's why I ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're booting off a flash drive, unless you're doing something you're not telling us, the hard drive is not needed for the operating system to run.  You can absolutely affect the hard drive on the system and not worry about the current operating system (on your USB stick).  It's analogous to formatting a USB memory stick from within Windows, for example.  No biggie.

That said, if you're going to overwrite data on your hard drive with data from your hard drive, you **will** break something.  Copy the image to another drive and make sure the disk you're *copying to* has no critical data, because it's not coming back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do it over the network - to run dd via netcat at the target system overwriting it with something you receive over the network. 
I tried this on my raspbian:

```
killall ifplugd
killall udevd
killall rsyslogd
killall cron
killall dbus-daemon
killall ntpd
killall thd
killall NetworkManager
umount /boot
swapoff -a 
nc -l 4000 | dd of=/dev/mmcblk0  bs=4096
```

on my PC:

> dd bs=4096 if=./My_BACKUP.2013.07.29th.img | nc 192.168.1.100 4000

and then waited....then screwed it up by pressing a key in the remote console. Don't press anything !!